# Java Eclipse Build Path Errors Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am just starting out with Maven. Is there any way to get maven dependencies to be added to the Eclipse project's build path? As of right now, my project is full of red x's due to Eclipse not being able to include some external class from one of these dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to setup you M2_REPO variable. This is a class path variable that tells eclipse where your designated maven repository is located.
You can setup M2_REPO by running the following command in your workspace.

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="replace with your Eclipse Workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace
```

Next make sure that your project has a maven fact applied by running the following command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in the workspace of your project. run

```
mvn clean package
```

just for good measure to make sure all your dependencies are resolved and available before restarting eclipse.

Once you restart eclipse again and bring your project up your issues should be resolved.

You should look up more information about these 2 commands and how to use them effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a ton of hassle and get the M2Eclipse plugin.  The plugin will handle all of the project setup for you and you don't have to worry about doing the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` commands.

http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/

Comment: My own experience confirms this. Easiest is to install via "Help > Eclipse Marketplace....", search for "Maven" and install the Plugin called "Maven Integration for Eclipse" by eclipse.org.

Answer (score 0):

have you executed

```
mvn eclipse:configure-workspace -Declipse.workspace=/path/to/workspace
```

?

You need to execute it so maven set the `M2_REPO` path to eclipse. Or you can set it manually.

Remenber to restart eclipse after you do so :P